# Double backslash in front of local URL

Tags: php, symfony

Is there a way to navigate to a file on a local location which uses a double backslash at the start like this: \192.168.1.1\folder\file.xml ?

I have tried several ways like this:

```
file_get_contents("\\192.168.1.1\folder\file.xml");
fopen("\\192.168.1.1\folder\file.xml", '');
```

But it keeps failing to open the file. while navigating to it locally seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need a backslash to escape every backslash (a backslash is the escape char in coding)

So you would have:

```
$addr = "\\\\192.168.1.1\\folder\\file.xml";
```

Comment: Or use single quotes? `'\\192.168.1.1\folder\file.xml'`. Would that work too?

Comment: or that too, but then you can't pass it variables.   without concatenating it outside of the string xD

Answer (score 2):

@Craig B - Beat me to the answer by few seconds, you should use double double

```
  "\\\\192.168.1.1\\folder\\file.xml"
```